# App Preview Resolution(1200x1600) For iPad Pro

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, app-preview

I am trying to make an App Preview for iPad Pro.

I recorded the video using QuickTime Player as recommended by the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-previews/). The resulting .mov file is 1920x1080.

I import into an App Preview iMovie project and then share as an App Preview. The resolution it wants to export as is 1920x1080 with no options to change it.

How do I get iMovie to export in the [desired resolution](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/?lang=en/#/dev4e413fcb8)(1600x1200)?

Comment: What is the device you are using for recording? because 1920x1080 ratio does not match iPad Pro screen ratio!

Comment: iPad Pro 11inch.